# Add a column to entries list using defineAdditionalEntryTableAttributes?

Tags: plugin-development

What I'm looking for is to add in a custom column that either has a checkmark or not based on if the entry's slug has a certain set of characters.

Example:

This would get a check: `sluggyslug-SC_01234X`

This would not: `sluggyslug`

I would be looking at the slug and matching via regex for the `SC_XXXXX` portion.

I see there is the hook `defineAdditionalEntryTableAttributes` and `getEntryTableAttributeHtml` but I get an error when I try to set them.

The code I tried in my plugin:

```
public function defineAdditionalEntryTableAttributes()
{
    return array(
        'something' => "Some Column",
    );
}

public function getEntryTableAttributeHtml(EntryModel $entry, $attribute)
{
    if ($attribute == 'something')
    {
        if (preg_match("/(?:SC_\w{5})$/", $entry->slug)) {
          return '<div class="center">&#x2713;</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to add the column, I just get this via the `getElements` ajax call.

```
CException
Property "Craft\EntryModel.something" is not defined.
```

Is there anyway to add a column like this?

Answer (score 1):

The error points to a missing corresponding field with handle 'something' in the entry model.